# Android camera access denied

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera

I am just trying to take a picture with the camera, and I am dealing with the permissions, the debugger is returning `java.io.IOException: Permission denied` but I cannot identify the mistake.

Here the camera button call:

```
btn_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                camera = new CameraPicture(getApplicationContext(), 10, 15);
                String[] permissionRequested = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                requestPermissions(permissionRequested, camera.getPermissionRequest());
            }
        });
    }
```

Here the interesting piece of code of `CameraPicture` class handling the camera:

```
public CameraPicture(Context context, int act_res_req_num, int perm_req_num) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cam_activity_result_req_num = act_res_req_num;
        this.cam_perm_req_num = perm_req_num;
    }

public Intent takePhotoIntent() throws IOException {
        File photoFile;
        Intent in = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (in.resolveActivity(this.context.getPackageManager()) != null && (photoFile = this.createImageFile()) != null) {
            in.putExtra("output", (Parcelable)Uri.fromFile((File)photoFile));
        }
        return in;
    }


    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory((String)Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);
        this.photoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

And here the permission method that seems to catch the exception:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if ((requestCode==camera.getPermissionRequest()) && (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
            try {
                startActivityForResult(camera.takePhotoIntent(), camera.getActResultRequest());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("ERROR MESSAGE: "+e);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error taking the picture ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to accesss the camera without permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Do you see something wrong on it?

**EDIT: forgot to show piece of manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
```

Comment: change this Manifest.permission.CAMERA to android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA

Comment: paste the manifest please.check the permission in manifest

Comment: Have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
in manifest?

Comment: have you declared inside the manifest?

Comment: yes, sorry forgot to include the manifest on the question...fixing it now....

Comment: this error is not really related to the camera. You have no access to the storage to write file (taken photo)

Comment: Check your target sdk version. If its 23 or > 23 then you must use runtime permission.

Comment: Why not post the whole stacktrace (and everything really) instead of updating the question with tiny bits that still obscure the big picture of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 112;

    btn_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
                        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CAMERAE );
                        } else {
                            camera = new CameraPicture(getApplicationContext(), 10, 15);
                            //open camera
                        }
                    } else {
                        camera = new CameraPicture(getApplicationContext(), 10, 15);
                        //open camera
                    }
                }
            });
        }

     /*get Permissions Result*/
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CAMERA: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    camera = new CameraPicture(getApplicationContext(), 10, 15);
                   //open camera
                } 
            }
        }
    }

       /*check permissions  for marshmallow*/

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! will give it a try!

Comment: in your code try to call camera = new CameraPicture(getApplicationContext(), 10, 15); in onRequestPermissionsResult and remove from onclick.Aslo check the  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)